# Accessing the parent object of a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, this

I have this function right here which takes the parts of my object and illuminates them successively with a delay (it switches the opacity of an element to 1 and then switches the previous element opacity to 0 to illuminate them successively).

The problem is that I cannot use the this keyword to access the parent objects parts in the `illuminateInternal` function.

This hinders any possible reuse of my object since I will have **maleBackNoZoom** and **maleBackFullZoom** objects.

I don't want to change the variable names of the `illuminateInternal` function when I re-use my object so I would like to use something like the `this` keyword in the `illuminateInternal` function as well.

```
maleBackNoZoom = {

    parts:{
    armsRight: findItemById("29") ,
    armsLeft: findItemById("28"),
    legsRight: findItemById("21"),
    legsLeft: findItemById("22"),
    back: findItemById("24"),
    buttocks: findItemById("23"), 
    neck: findItemById("26"),
    head: findItemById("27")
     },

  illuminate: function() {
    var propertiesToIlluminate = [], prop, illuminateInternal, i = 0, delay = 200, intervalId;
    for (prop in this.parts) {
        propertiesToIlluminate.push(prop);
    }

    illuminateInternal = function () {
        var property = propertiesToIlluminate[i];
        var previousProperty = propertiesToIlluminate[i-1];
        maleBackNoZoom.parts[property].opacity = 1;
         console.log(previousProperty);
        if (typeof previousProperty !== 'undefined'){
        maleBackNoZoom.parts[previousProperty].opacity = 0;
         }

        paper.view.update();
        i++;

        if (i === propertiesToIlluminate.length) {

            maleBackNoZoom.parts[property].opacity = 0;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            setInterval(function(){paper.view.update()},delay);
        }
    };
    intervalId = setInterval(illuminateInternal, delay);
}  
}
```

Comment: outside your `illuminateInternal` function define `var self = this` and call `self.parentFunctions` inside your inner function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define local variable inside `illuminate` method which will store reference to its object. And then you can use it as alias of `this`.

```
var self = this;

illuminateInternal = function () {
    ..
    self.parts[property].opacity = 1;
}
```